# A conceptual question on implicit partial derivatives in maltivariate situations

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative, implicit-differentiation

Say q is a function of two variables m and H:
$$q = f_{1}(m,H)$$
Further, m and H are related to a third variable L:
$$L = f_{2}(m,H)$$
I believe that, using the idea of the total derivative, it is correct to say:
$$dq = \frac{\partial q}{\partial m}dm + \frac{\partial q}{\partial H}dH$$
Similarly, $dm = \frac{\partial m}{\partial L}dL$ and $dH = \frac{\partial H}{\partial L}dL$ should also be correct.
Given this background, are the following equations correct?
$$\frac{dq}{dm} = \frac{\partial q}{\partial m} + \frac{\partial q}{\partial H}\frac{dH}{dm}$$
or
$$
\frac{dq}{dm} = \frac{\partial q}{\partial m} + \frac{\partial q}{\partial H}
                \frac{\frac{\partial H}{\partial L}}{\frac{\partial m}{\partial L}}$$
If these are correct, then are they circular? In other words, would $\frac{dq}{dm}$ be obtainable directly from the first equation too, with the same result?
Any help and guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: $L = f_2(m, H)$ means that when possible $m = f_3(L, H)$ so $dm = \frac {\partial m}{\partial L}dL + \frac {\partial m}{\partial H} dH$. Same for $dH$.

Comment: Thanks @Kaster. You are correct. But it turns out that the form of the function f2 is such that it is not possible for m to be isolated and expressed in terms of L and H (ditto for H). What do you think about the final equation? Is it correct but unnecessary?